# How do i make this query sql injection proof?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

How can i make this query sql injection proof?

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 16");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msg_id=$row['item_id'];
$message=$row['item_content'];
}
```

Or can someone show me some examples, or send me a link to a tutorial
I'm very new to this and if anyone could help me it would be great! :)

Comment: ummm there is nothing to be able to `inject` into the query..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That query is already "SQL injection proof".

SQL injection attacks happen when you take an external string, and concatenate it into your query without using bind variables, escaping or proper sanitization.

For example, if your query looked like this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates where order_ref = '$order_ref' ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 16");
```

Then you would have an issue if the variable `$order_ref` could be influenced by the environment (an HTTP query parameter, command line argument, basically anything that can be influenced by the user). If someone could pass a value into your application like "`'; delete from updates;`" then you would have a problem.

One solution in my above example would be to first escape the values in `$order_ref` like this:

```
$safe_order_ref = mysql_real_escape_string($order_ref);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates where order_ref = '$safe_order_ref' ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 16");
```

Answer (score 1):

It already is since you aren't using any user input to construct it.

Answer (score 0):

It **is** injection-proof. Injection happens when you construct your SQL from several strings, of which some come from the user, in the $_GET, or $_POST, or $_COOKIE collection. Yours is static - there's no place to inject.

Comment: From the user, or *(and that's something many people forget)* from any possible non-trusted source *(and a trusted source shouldn't be trusted either : it can suffer some failure, be hacked, ...)*

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN: if the trusted source is already hijacked, SQL injection is the least of your worries.

Comment: Not always : in some cases, if the data you insert into your database is not what you wanted, it's not necessarily a catastrophy -- as long as it doesn't destroy your database or application.

Answer (score 0):

My man.  You are just pulling data from your database.  SQL injection happens when a user is providing input by a form or GET variable (GET not recommended) that you will use in the query itself.

Lets say you have a form that posts the name of someone.

Your SQL would look like:

```
$query='SELECT * FROM people WHERE name='.$_POST['name'];
```

You would need to clean the data posted by the user with mysql_real_escape_string() or some other SQL cleaning function.

Another thing: nothing is SQL injection proof.  There always seems to be a funny little way to exploit.  What you want to do is make it so time consuming people give up.

Keep on keeping on brother.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure his original query is actually SQL injection proof

Answer (score 0):

> SQL injection is a code injection
>   technique that exploits a security
>   vulnerability occurring in the
>   database layer of an application. The
>   vulnerability is present when user
>   input is either incorrectly filtered
>   for string literal escape characters
>   embedded in SQL statements or user
>   input is not strongly typed and
>   thereby unexpectedly executed. It is
>   an instance of a more general class of
>   vulnerabilities that can occur
>   whenever one programming or scripting
>   language is embedded inside another.
>   SQL injection attacks are also known
>   as SQL insertion attacks.

For more detail see [HERE](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_injection). After reading this you should know why everybody say, your query is already SQL injection proof.